# Cannot set body as FormDataMultiPart on exchange in apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a use-case where I need to send FormDataMultiPart through exchange body, which goes in a REST service call.

REST end point:

```
public Response sendttachments(final FormDataMultiPart bodyPart) {
//Do Something
}
```

Camel Processor:

```
FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
File file = new File("pathToFile");
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
FormDataBodyPart fdp1 = new FormDataBodyPart(FormDataContentDisposition.name("emailRequest").build(),
                    someObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
FormDataBodyPart fdp2 = new FormDataBodyPart(
FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName("fileName").build(), targetStream,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(fdp1).bodyPart(fdp2);

    exchange.getIn().setBody(Entity.entity(formDataMultiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
```

I get the following exception :

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No
>   type converter available to convert from type:
>   javax.ws.rs.client.Entity to the required type: java.io.InputStream
>   with value
>   Entity{entity=org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart@3e90d6b2,
>   variant=Variant[mediaType=multipart/form-data, language=null,
>   encoding=null], annotations=[]}

Am I missing some conversion type? or something else. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to provide more details, camel version in use, how you configure rest etc. Also Camel rest-dsl is not JAX-RS stuff, if you want to use that, then use Apache CXF etc.